Google pub sub not triggering on the given scheduled time
In my code i have a function that checks for pending crypto transactions and updates the status based on a certain logic. Every time a new crypto transaction is created a message is sent to a pub sub topic to be triggered after 30s and check the status of that transaction. The problem is that the 30s timer is ignored and the trigger is launching immediately not giving the crypto transaction a chance to be processed.
This is a code sample, i am using firebase cloud functions and i run this function to schedule the topic using "@google-cloud/pubsub": "^4.5.0",:
  public async scheduleNextCheck({
    uid,
    operationID,
    pendingCryptoOperation,
  }: {
    uid: string;
    operationID: string;
    pendingCryptoOperation: Operation;
  }) {
    const pubsub = new PubSub();
    const data = {
      operationID,
      uid,
      "api-version": "v1",
      differenceInSeconds: 0,
    };
    const publishTime = this.calculateNextTriggerTimeStamp(
      pendingCryptoOperation
    );

    // Convert Firestore Timestamp to milliseconds
    const milliseconds =
      publishTime.seconds * 1000 +
      Math.floor(publishTime.nanoseconds / 1000000);

    // Create a Date object for publishTime
    let publishDate = new Date(milliseconds);

    // Calculate the difference between now and publishTime
    const now = new Date();
    const differenceInMilliseconds = publishDate.getTime() - now.getTime();
    const differenceInSeconds = Math.floor(differenceInMilliseconds / 1000);
    data.differenceInSeconds = differenceInSeconds;

    // Ensure publishTime is in the future
    if (differenceInMilliseconds < 0) {
      console.warn("Publish time is in the past. Adjusting to now.");
      publishDate = now; // or handle this case appropriately
    }

    const messageId = await pubsub
      .topic(this.runtimeConfig.pubSubPendingOperationsTopic, {
        enableOpenTelemetryTracing: true,
      })
      .publishMessage({
        json: data,
        publishTime: Timestamp.fromDate(publishDate),
      });

    Logger.info(`Trigger scheduled for operation ${operationID}`, {
      operationID,
      status: OperationStatus.pending,
      uid,
      messageId,
      publishTime: publishDate.toISOString(),
      differenceInSeconds,
    });
  }

and this is the calculateNextTriggerTimeStamp  just for reference:
  public calculateNextTriggerTimeStamp(operation: Operation): Timestamp {
    const { createdAt } = operation;
    const now = Date.now();
    const fiveMinutesInMillis = 5 * 60 * 1000;
    const thirtySecondsInMillis = 30 * 1000;

    // Time elapsed since the operation was created
    const timeElapsed = now - createdAt.toMillis();

    // First 5 minutes: check every 30 seconds
    if (timeElapsed <= fiveMinutesInMillis) {
      return Timestamp.fromMillis(now + thirtySecondsInMillis);
    }

    // After 5 minutes, start increasing the interval
    const intervals = [
      { duration: 10 * 60 * 1000, interval: 1 * 60 * 1000 }, // Next 10 minutes: every 1 minute
      { duration: 30 * 60 * 1000, interval: 5 * 60 * 1000 }, // Next 30 minutes: every 5 minutes
      { duration: 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000, interval: 15 * 60 * 1000 }, // Next 2 hours: every 15 minutes
      { duration: 6 * 60 * 60 * 1000, interval: 30 * 60 * 1000 }, // Next 6 hours: every 30 minutes
      { duration: 34 * 60 * 60 * 1000, interval: 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000 }, // Remaining time to 48 hours: every 1 hour
    ];

    let cumulativeTime = fiveMinutesInMillis;

    for (const step of intervals) {
      cumulativeTime += step.duration;
      if (timeElapsed <= cumulativeTime) {
        const remainingTimeInStep = cumulativeTime - timeElapsed;
        const nextTriggerInMillis =
          step.interval - (remainingTimeInStep % step.interval);
        return Timestamp.fromMillis(now + nextTriggerInMillis);
      }
    }

    throw ErrorMessages.TaskExceedsMaxInterval;
  }

Why the scheduling is not working ? Is there a problem in the package itself ?

Also see the documentation for the publishTime field: “ The time at which the message was published, populated by the server when it receives the topics.publish call. It must not be populated by the publisher in a topics.publish call.”

@TimMoore If that is the case then i believe the package @google-cloud/pubsub should not allow that field to be passed. I am using TS and one of the allowed fields is publishTime so that is why is used the field. Otherwise i would have not done that.

I agree with you, but that’s not how Google designed it, unfortunately. I find that their APIs are not always the most user friendly.

In the answers to the question I linked above, they mention alternatives that can be used to schedule actions in the future, specifically Cloud Tasks

Yeah i will switch to cloud tasks since unfortunately pub sub does not offer scheduling. I wanted to keep my endpoints hidden by making my function an onPublish trigger which was working when using pub sub but now with cloud task i have to make the cloud function an http function so that cloud task can call it.
Do you know a way that allows cloud tasks to call pub sub using the api to trigger an on publish event ?
